# Plot a plotly object from a list based on user selection from a Update UI dropdown

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny App which stores plotly objects in a list and I want the user to select from the dropdown `X` number of stocks they want to perform some analysis to. Then I use some function to split the time series into training and testing data.

What I want to do is update the UI so that the user has the option to select a symbol from a new dropdown (next to the plot area) and then it will generate this new plot. (i.e. by filtering the list of plots by the `input$symbol2` name.

I am stuck on the `plotsList` at the very end of the code.

Code and App:

```
    #
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidymodels)
library(timetk)
library(plotly)

# library(shiny)
# library(shinyWidgets)
# library(shinyjs)
#
# library(tidyverse)
# library(tidyquant)
# library(Deloitte)
# library(gtExtras)
# library(gt)
# library(htmltools)
#
# library(modeltime)
# library(tidymodels)
# library(timetk)
# library(lubridate)
# library(parsnip)


FANG
uniqueSymbols = unique(FANG$symbol)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("List error"),

  shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
    inputId = "var_to_forecast_CF1",
    label = h4("Variable To Predict"),
    choices = c("open", "high"),
    selected = "open"
  ),


  verbatimTextOutput("formula_to_estimate_1"),

  airYearpickerInput(
    inputId = "yearly_range",
    label = "Select range of years:",
    range = TRUE, value = c(Sys.Date()-365*10, Sys.Date())
  ),

  shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
    inputId = "symbol",
    label = h4("Select symbol"),
    choices = uniqueSymbols,
    selected = "Total",
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list(
      size = 3
    )
  ),
  actionButton(inputId = "apply", label = "Aplicar", icon = icon("play")),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  formula_to_estimate = reactive({
    #formula(paste0(input$var_to_forecast_CF1,  "~Periodo", sep = ""))
    paste0(input$var_to_forecast_CF1, "~", "close") %>%
      as.formula()
  })

  output$formula_to_estimate_1 = renderText({
    deparse(as.formula(formula_to_estimate()))
  })

  # Compute Assessment period

  # compute the "assess" part of the "time_series_split" function:

  assessmentDuration = reactive({
    (year(input$yearly_range[2]) - year(input$yearly_range[1])) * 12
  })

  # A list of 2:
  data_to_model = eventReactive(input$apply, {
    FANG %>%
      filter(symbol %in% input$symbol) %>%
      split(., .$symbol)
  })

  splits = eventReactive(input$apply, {
    data_to_model() %>%
      map(.,  ~.x %>%
            time_series_split(
              assess = assessmentDuration(),
              #assess = "18 months",
              cumulative = TRUE
            )
      )
  })

  plotsList = eventReactive({
    splits() %>%
      map(., ~.x %>%
            ggplot(aes(x = Periodo, y = diff_from_base_year), color = "#041e42") +
            geom_line(size = 1) +
            #facet_wrap(~input$symbol, ncol = 1) +
            labs(
              x = "Date", y = "r",
              title = "my title"
            ) +
            theme_momura() %>%
            ggplotly()
      )
  })
  # How can update the UI and filter a single stock to plot?
  output$plot = renderPlotly({
    plotsList[[!!sym(input$symbol2)]] # STUCK HERE...........
  })


}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you make your app reproducible? there are some bugs; and function `time_series_split` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry! its from a timeseries package, will update with packages now!

Comment: First, you have `plotsList = eventReactive({` that does not have a trigger. Changing that for a simple `reactive` solves that error; but it does not generates a plot. Besides that, I think your question is not 100% clear yet. Could you narrow this further maybe with a simpler app that uses simpler data?

Comment: Thanks! I have a list of plotly list items and I want the user to select from the list which plot they would like to show, the lists are named. JUst wondering how I can do it.